# Lucene: How to do wildcard search inside a Term?

Tags: search, lucene, wildcard

I've the following lucene index:

```
Document A
item = level:(1)
item = level:(2)
item = level:(3)

Document B
item = level:(1)
item = level:(4)
```

Suppose I want to search for all documents which contain level:(1) AND level:(2) ?

The Lucene query could be like:

```
"item:level\:\(1\) AND level\:\(2\)"
```

but is it also possible to do something like this:

```
"item:level\:\(1 OR 2\)"
```

?

(The reason for this is that I don't want to repeat the string `"level\:"`)

Comment: Why do you not want to repeat "level:"? There may be other solutions depending on your reason.

Comment: I would guess that building up and sending a long text string to Lucene will degrade performance ?

Comment: Unless you are including thousands of "level:" strings, I doubt you will notice any perceivable difference in performance. I would recommend you try writing some tests to see just how much performance degrades as you add more "level:" strings.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to make `level` your query parser's default field, allowing your query to be reduced to:

```
(1 OR 2)
```

However, I suspect that this isn't exactly what you're looking for...

According to the [Lucene query parser syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html), what you're asking for cannot be done using the boolean operators (`AND` and `OR`). However, it looks like it may be possible using the plus (`+`) and minus (`-`) operators. According to the documentation:

> Lucene supports using parentheses to group multiple clauses to a single field.
>
> To search for a title that contains both the word "return" and the phrase "pink panther" use the query:
>
> `title:(+return +"pink panther")`

This is not exactly what you're looking for, but it may be suitable. I am unsure as to how an `OR` clause would be written in this manner.

Comment: @Adam
I must admit that my example is somehow confusing. The field is "item" and the content is "level:(1)". (It's maybe confusing that the content also includes an ':' sign)

I will try your solution.
It will be something like "item:(+level \\(1\\) \\(2\\))" ?